# Find source of string in url wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm stuck with a problem I can't seem to find a solution to. A friend asked to make a few changes on his website. The theme is BeTheme (licensed) if this helps. The site was done by some guy he hired online of one of those remote job sites, and has lost contact since.

What's happening is there's this `/?v=abc123string` string that is always added to the URL, doesn't matter what page is being opened. Doesn't matter if it is the `wp-admin` dashboard, the frontend, wherever, the string is always appended to the URL. **And it's always the same.**

I've gone through `functions.php` etc, can't find anything in that regard there. I've also tested moving from the child-theme to the base theme provided (BeTheme) which is up to date, and the string is always there.

I've used grep trying to find any file with the string (the part AFTER `?v=`) in question: nothing.
I've searched the database for said string, nothing either. Can anyone suggest how can I find where is this coming from? I'm out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe in the `.htaccess` file at the top level of the WordPress installation?

Comment: first placed I looked, not there either.